# How to setpath= to Program Files if Program Files (x86) doesn't exist in batch?

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, path, x86, winrar

**Here's the script. The objective is to extract the Rar files in the folder to a particular folder. The problem is that I need the path to WinRar to change to Program Files is Program Files (x86) isn't on the system. How can I do that? Thank you!**

```
@echo off
@set local

set dirA=C:\Users\%username%\Desktop

\SpearsCraftBox\Batches

set dirE=C:\Users\%username%\AppData

\Roaming\.minecraft

set dirC=C:\Users\%username%\Desktop

\SpearsCraftBox\Batches

cd %dirA%
```

**set path="C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\";%path%**

```
echo.
echo All files in %dirA% to be uncompressed
echo.


echo.

FOR %%i IN (*.rar) do (
unrar x "%%~ni.rar" "%dirE%"
move "%%~ni.rar" "%dirC%"
echo completed uncompressing "%%i" and moved 

archives or archive to "%dirC%"
)

goto eof


:eof

echo.
echo "Task Completed"
echo.
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to set the path every time you run it? Should be a one time thing unless you are distributing the file to others in which case how would you know if they had winrar installed and that they installed the 32 bit version?

Comment: Hmmm... stackoverflow won't let me compliment you that you're trying to do something regarding Minecraft :-P

Answer (score 3):

There are environment variables defined for the Program Files directory: `%ProgramFiles%` and `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`.

```
IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\WinRAR" (
  SET pth="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\WinRAR"
)
IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR" (
  SET pth="%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR"
)


IF NOT EXIST %pth% (
    ECHO WinRar not found.
    GOTO :EOF
)
...
"%pth%unrar" x "%%~ni.rar" "%dirE%"
...
```